# Floating point comparison in linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, floating-point, comparison

I am trying to achieve this in Linux sell

```
set a=1.2345
set b=2.34

if (abs(a-b)>1.2) then
...
endif
```

There are several issues that I am facing:

- dealing with floating point
- comparison ( using $ vs not using it)
- calculating the absolute value

I am not able to resolve my issue and handle all of them at once. I have searched many many pages and some solutions don't work for my me. For example I don't seem to have the abs function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you should have an `abs` function? Why do you think `abs(a-b)` would call it with that argument? Why do you think `set a=1.2345` sets the bash variable `$a`? Why do you think `endif` ends an `if` statement? Why do you think bash supports floating point numbers? Are you perhaps trying to write `(t)csh` code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` does not do floating point.  The standard utility `bc` does. This uses `bc` to perform the test that you ask:

```
a=1.2345
b=2.34

r=$(echo "($a - $b)^2 > 1.2^2" | bc)
if [ "$r" -eq 1 ]
then
        echo True
else
        echo False
fi
```

Since `bc` does not have an `abs` function, the code above uses the simple work-around of squaring each side of the inequality.  `bc` returns `1` if the test is true or `0` if it is false.  This output is saved in the variable `r`.  The value of `r` is tested for equality to `1` with `[ "$r" -eq 1 ]`.  The `if` statement responds accordingly.